# Determine whether function is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, upper-lower-bounds

I'm trying to determine, whether the function:

$\frac{2\sin x-5\cos x}{2x^{2}+3}$ is bounded.

These are the steps I followed:
$\left |\frac{2\sin x}{2x^{2}+3}  \right | + \left | \frac{5\cos x}{2x^{2}+3} \right | \leq \left | \frac{2}{2x^{2}+3} \right|*1+\left | \frac{5}{2x^{2}+3} \right |*1$

And I put $0$ for $x$ to get the upper bound. Then I got $\leq \frac{2}{3}+\frac{5}{3}$. However, that upper bound is incorrect.

Can you tell me where I did a mistake? Also how would I find the lower bound?

Comment: Why did you set $0$ for $x$ to find the upper bound? Where does $\frac{2}{2x^2+3}$ take on its maximum value?

Comment: @AnthonyTer My guess is that the fraction has maximum value for $x=0$, because any other number would increase the denominator. Am I not seeing something?

Comment: Anyway, are you asked for the *least* upper bound?

Comment: @Peter Sorry; you are right. Why do you think that bound is incorrect? It bounds the function. Do you need a tight upper bound?

Comment: @AnthonyTer Oh, I got something mixed up in my head and I thought that I have to find the "best" upper bound, but you are right, my upper bound is just fine. Sorry! However, how would I find the lower bound?

Comment: @Peter You've bounded the absolute value of your function, so the bound works for both the upper and lower bound. So a lower bound would be $-\frac73$

Comment: @AnthonyTer I just change the value from $7/3$ to $-7/3$ and I have the lower bound, when I bound the absolute value of a function?

Comment: Yep, you got it

Comment: @AnthonyTer That's a gamechanger. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, the mistake is when you put it to zero as it isn't the maximum of the equation.

Rewrite the equation using  $a\sin(x)+b\cos(x) = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin(2x)$ and you can derive and find the maximum of the function (think it is how it should be done).

Comment: I don't think the derivative is necessary.